# Why can't I put this image on the right side of the page?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on this blog-like webpage on this URL:

https://cyhcode-webpage.cyh1368.repl.co/project.html

I wanted to put an image on the right side of the text descriptions.

I've tried floating all of them (The description and the image), but that would make some trouble if I'd like to add some other descriptions or texts.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: show your code. try using 2 div and use `float` properties for left and right. also, use `clear:both`

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid `float` and use `flex` instead. This method also lets you avoid the need to `clear`. Here's an example:

```css
li { 
 display: flex; 
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 margin-bottom: 1rem;
}


li h2 {
  padding: .5rem 1rem .5rem .5rem; 
  flex: 1;
}

li img {
  max-width: 200px;
}

/* Presentational */

ul, li { list-style: none;  padding: 0; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2>This is one of the best games I've made in python using Turtle Graphics. </h2>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="">
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>Instructions: </h2>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/150" alt="">    
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>Use WASD or arrow keys to move you(yellow square).</h2>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/150" alt="">    
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>You get a point if you eat a food(white square).</h2>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/150" alt="">    
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>Don't let the computer(orange square) eat too much!</h2>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/150" alt="">    
  </li>
</ul>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1gk2dqjs/15/)